# Date in ControlParameter causes error with date format

Tags: asp.net, sql, vb.net, sqldatasource

I have a vb.net web site that has a SQLDataSource with a date as a ControlParameter. This works okay in UK, but when the same page is opened in Germany it produces an error due to the different date format.

See example code below

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SQL" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:xxxxxxxx %>"
    SelectCommand="
       SELECT * 
       from data
       where 
       DATEADD(minute, time, date) > convert(datetime,@dt,104)
">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="DateSelection" Name="dt" PropertyName="SelectedItem.text" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Would someone know how to resolve this problem

Thanks

Comment: The error is: Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Comment: Please add examples of a date that works, and a date that causes the error.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand your SQL logic so assuming that the logic is sound, I suspect that the main cause is because the output from `SelectedItem` is being treated as a `string`.

So a `string` of value `"31/12/2014"` can be interpreted as 31 December 2014 if the date format of the client PC is "dd/MM/yyyy".

But if the client PC's date format is "MM/dd/yyyy" then there will be an error since there is no 31st month.

Instead of using `ControlParameter` on the front end, you can try setting the `SelectCommand` on the back end, that should give you more freedom in manipulating your data.

aspx page:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SQL" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:xxxxxxxx %>" 
    SelectCommand="" >
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

aspx.vb page:

```
'assuming "SelectedItem" is a textbox
dim str As String = Convert.ToDateTime(SelectedItem.Text).ToString("dd MMM yyyy")

SQL.SelectCommand = "SELECT * from data where DATEADD(minute, time, date) > convert(datetime," + str + ",104)"
```

The reason why I converted the date to the "dd MMM yyyy" format is because regardless of what date format a PC is using, "31 Dec 2014" will always be treated as 31 December 2014.